# how to add ternary operators within JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

trying to nest ternary operators for cleaner code i will resort to if statements if nothing else.

```
if(x==="name"){
childMap = c.map((item,i) => (
  {i}>0? <span> and </span> : '' : ( legalOrMinor === this.ofAge(item[1]) ? <span key={i} className="childInfo">{item[0]} </span> : '')
));
return (
  <span>
  {childMap}
  </span>
);
```

any ideas on how to make this work? if i add the first ternary to the end, it almost works, but I need the "and" to come after the first iteration.

Any other logic i have tried is not friendly.

Comment: IMO you should extract this logic. It's not quite clear what you're intending here in the first place; there's no `{i}` syntax in JS, nor is it clear what you mean by `... : '' : ...`. You'll need to state your requirements more clearly, or at least in code that's sensical.

Comment: Thamks for the input. so... this is in react the "i" is a generated index by the map. so i use it to iterate thru parrallel arrays at the same time, as well as provide a unique key for the <divs> 

the main thing I'm trying to do is something like this:

"item" {thing} "item" {thing} "item" {thing} "item"

i want to say "put this thing after each item EXCEPT the last one. 

or 

put this thing before each item EXCEPT the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesting ternary expressions is a nightmare and I strongly suggest that you avoid it. If you absolute must, remember to keep the structure correct. A ternary with the structure `a ? b : c : d` is not a valid statement.

A ternary looks like this:

```
let myVar = (someBoolean ? ifTrue : ifFalse);
```

A nested ternary would look like this:

```
let myVar = (someBoolean ? ifTrue : (someOtherBoolean ? ifTrue : ifFalse));
```

Note that the parentheses make it slightly clearer what's going on, but not much. Try reasoning about what myVar will be across all four permutations of what states `someBoolean` and `someOtherBoolean` might be... and that's only with *two* nested ternaries.

Beyond a single ternary, it's almost always better to just break it out into `if` statements. In React this means that you'll need to do it either outside of the JSX (like in the `render` function before your return statement) or in an immediately-invoked function operator. E.g.:

In `render` body before return:

```
render() {
    let something = undefined;
    if(this.state.foo === true) {
        if(this.state.bar === "baz") {
            something = <span>baz</span>;
        } else if(this.state.bar === "qux") {
            something = <span>qux</span>;
        }
    }
    return <div>something</div>;
}
```

In IIFE (this SHOULD work but I'm too lazy to check right now):

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>{(function(){
            let something = undefined;
            if(this.state.foo === true) {
                if(this.state.bar === "baz") {
                    something = <span>baz</span>;
                } else if(this.state.bar === "qux") {
                    something = <span>qux</span>;
                }
            }
            return something;
        })()}</div>
    );
}
```

Actually even an IIFE should probably just be moved out into its own thing for sanity's sake:

```
returnSomething() {
    let something = undefined;
    if(this.state.foo === true) {
        if(this.state.bar === "baz") {
            something = <span>baz</span>;
        } else if(this.state.bar === "qux") {
            something = <span>qux</span>;
        }
    }
    return something;
}
render() {
    return (
        <div>{this.returnSomething()}</div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I guess I just don't like the idea of writing "<span>qux</span>.

Comment: so the issue im having is that I can't figure out how to do this with map? I need to add an "and" in my map of stuff, "item" {and} "item" {and} "item.

Comment: @ElijahLucian Remember that the function within `map()` needs to `return` a value, otherwise it returns `undefined`. The whole idea of `map()` is to transform one array into another array by processing each item into something new. In the code in your post you're not returning from the function and that could be a problem with whatever you're trying now too.